# palindrome check in ruby

Tags: ruby

Why is this code giving wrong output for this input ?

```
def palindrome?(str)
   str.delete('^a-zA-Z')
   str.downcase 
   str == str.reverse
end


INPUT = "A man, a plan, a canal -- Panama"

OUTPUT = Failure/Error: palindrome?("A man, a plan, a canal -- Panama").should be_true, "Incorrect results for input: \"A man, a plan, a canal -- Panama\""
      Incorrect results for input: "A man, a plan, a canal -- Panama"
    # spec.rb:7:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
    # ./lib/rspec_runner.rb:36:in `block in run_rspec'
    # ./lib/rspec_runner.rb:32:in `run_rspec'
    # ./lib/rspec_runner.rb:23:in `run'
    # lib/graders/weighted_rspec_grader.rb:6:in `grade!'
    # ./grade:31:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 4):

The delete and downcase methods on Strings do not modify the String itself, they return a changed copy. If you want to modify the receiver, use the bang variants:

```
str.delete!('[^a-zA-Z]')
str.downcase!
```

---

on second thoughts, don't do this, because horrible things like this happen:

```
string = "hello123"
palindrome?(string)
string    #=> "OLLEH"
```

Instead, make a copy of the argument and modify that:

```
def palindrome?(arg)
  str = arg.dup
  str.delete!('[^a-zA-Z]')
  str.downcase!
  str == str.reverse
end
```

Comment: Or since the non-modifying versions return a new string you could just chain them: `str == str.delete('[^a-zA-Z]').downcase.reverse`.

Comment: ah yes -- i'd say yours is more idiomatic.

Comment: But! the left hand side will still have non-alpha chars in, and also needs to be downcased.

Answer (score 0):

How to find the total number of palindromes for a string

```
class String 
  def palindrome?
    self == self.strip.reverse
  end
  def sub_str_arr
    (0..self.length).inject([]){|ai,i|
      (1..self.length - i).inject(ai){|aj,j|
        aj << self[i,j]
      }
    }
  end
  def num_palindromes
    return -1 if self.length > 100000000
    self.sub_str_arr.reject!{|item| item if item.length < 2 || !item.palindrome?}.size
  end
end

puts "dabadbadbadbdbadbadbdabdbadbadbadbadbadadadbdbdbdbadbdabadbadbdbadbabdabdbbdabdabdbadba".num_palindromes
```

Comment: the total should be 52 BTW